# Variable is not working at condition

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, where-clause

The following code is the part of a stored procedure. here i am using few variables. 
the logic of this program is, a string will contain values separated by comma(,) from that we need to get each string by splitting the input sting. now the separated strings will be used in a query to execute.

sample code

@cond1-->input string(eg)(''mark'',''lewis'',)

@splt-->separated strings (i.e) mark

```
Declare @pos INT, @len INT
set @pos = 0
set @len = 0
WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @cond1, @pos+1)>0
        BEGIN
            set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @cond1, @pos+1) - @pos;
            set @splt = SUBSTRING(@cond1, @pos, @len);
            if @pid = '' 
                Begin
                    set @pid= @splt;
                End
            Else
                Begin
                    set @pid= @pid + ' or positionid='+ @splt;
                End
            set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @cond1, @pos+@len) +1;
        END
END
print 'SELECT day1,day1leg1,day1leg2,hccyamt,pfid,pcfcccy,pcfcbank,maturitydate,availeddate FROM rskpcfc WHERE 
        pcfcid='+@pcid;
SELECT day1,day1leg1,day1leg2,hccyamt,pfid,pcfcccy,pcfcbank,maturitydate,availeddate FROM rskpcfc WHERE 
        pcfcid=@pcid;
```

When executing the above code,

```
exec [dbo].[pcfc_select] @status='APCASSD',@cond1='''pc14-46-119'',''pc14-47-119'','
```

Print statement will give the following

```
SELECT day1,day1leg1,day1leg2,hccyamt,pfid,pcfcccy,pcfcbank,maturitydate,availeddate FROM rskpcfc WHERE 
        pcfcid='pc14-46-119' or pcfcid='pc14-47-119'
```

but select statement returns empty table even it has values.

Every thing works fine except the last select command

I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that gets executed at the last line is :

```
SELECT day1,day1leg1,day1leg2,hccyamt,pfid,pcfcccy,pcfcbank,maturitydate,availeddate 
FROM rskpcfc
WHERE pcfcid='''pc14-46-119'' or pcfcid=''pc14-47-119'''
```

and not the one you see when printing. You cannot dynamically add conditions to the where clause using parameters substitution.

To achieve this you should use dynamic sql execution using sp_executesql procedure or exec.